# SpringBoot Simple Question i don't find the solution how to solve this

Tags: java, spring-boot

How Can i return an `ArrayList` using `ResponseEntity`

Code :

```
List<String> userName=new ArrayList<>();

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public @ResponseBody List<userName> getAllHospitals() throws Exception {
        return new ResponseEntity<userName>(userName,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if "userName" is the name of your class, then rename it to **Username**, because it's a good Java convention to make class name start with capital letter.

Second, you need to name the method properly, describing exactly what it does. So, if you are building a method to get all users (by your Mapping), then the method is supposed to be "getAllUsers", not "getAllHospitals"

If you need to return a list from your mapping method, then you need to use the proper generic form:

```
    @GetMapping("/users")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<List<Username>> getAllUsers() throws Exception {
        List<Username> usernames = new ArrayList<>();
        usernames.add(new Username(....)); // substitute with parameters of that class
        return new ResponseEntity<List<Username>>(usernames,HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```